# ¿Cómo vaciar un array en Javascript?

Tags: javascript, array

¿Existe alguna manera de vaciar un array o simplemente hay que eliminarlo?

Por ejemplo:

```
A = [1,2,3,4];
```

¿Como se vaciaría?

P.D.: Esta [pregunta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1232040/how-do-i-empty-an-array-in-javascript) ya existe en la versión inglesa, pero me parecía interesante retomarla y adaptarla para usuarios hispanohablantes.

Comment: Estas pensando en traducir la respuesta? Creo que eso seria un buen aporte.

Comment: @KennyBarrera Mi idea es traducirla si :) Pero voy a dejar unas horas por si alguien quiere hacerlo o aportar algo mejor.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Si se le asigna una nueva instancia al array se puede limpiar:

```js
var numeros = [1,2,3,4,5];
console.log(numeros);

numeros = []; // nueva instancia
console.log(numeros);
```

También utilizando el método `splice()` que elimina del array original y retorna  los elemento en el rango especificado. Por lo que tendrías otra instancia de un array:

```js
    var numeros = [1,2,3,4,5];
    console.log(numeros);

    var elementosRemovidos = numeros.splice(0, numeros.length);
    console.log(elementosRemovidos);
    console.log(numeros);
```

También utilizando el método `pop()` de *JavaScript* que elimina el ultimo elemento del *array*. Entonces para limpiarlo completamente tendrías que ejecutar el método `pop()` por cada elemento del *array*:

```js
 var numeros = [1,2,3,4,5];
  console.log(numeros);
  numeros.pop(); // elimina el elemento 5
  console.log(numeros);

while(numeros.length > 0)
  numeros.pop(); 

 console.log(numeros);
```

Y por ultimo asignando 0 a la propiedad `length`. Según la [documentación](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/length):

> Puede establecer la propiedad *length* para truncar una matriz en
> cualquier momento. Al extender una matriz cambiando su propiedad
> *length*, el número de elementos reales no aumenta; por ejemplo, si
> establece longitud a 3 cuando es actualmente 2, la matriz todavía
> contiene sólo 2 elementos. Por lo tanto, la propiedad *length* no indica
> necesariamente el número de valores definidos en la matriz

Así que esto es totalmente valido y limpia el array:

```js
var numeros = [1,2,3,4,5];
numeros.length = 0;
console.log(numeros);
```

Comment: Se te olvida una muy importante: `numeros.length=0;`

Comment: para que no de error debe ser mayor a 0 la longitud si no da error

Answer (score 9):

Hay 4 métodos para limpiar un arreglo.

**Método 1**

```
A = [];
```

Este es el método Optimo pero debes de tener cuidado por que pierdes la referencia del arreglo original, y si la variable es de tipo `const` podras tener errores.

**Método 2**

```
A.length = 0
```

Esto borrará la matriz existente estableciendo su longitud en `0`. Algunos han argumentado que esto no puede funcionar en todas las implementaciones de JavaScript, pero resulta que este no es el caso. También funciona cuando se utiliza "**strict mode**" en **`ECMAScript 5`**  porque la propiedad de longitud de una matriz es una `read/write` por lo cual permite sobreescribir el valor.

**Método 3**

```
A.splice(0,A.length)
```

Esta función devolverá una matriz con todos los elementos eliminados, y tambien devolverá una copia de la matriz original.

**Método 4**

```
while(A.length) {
    A.pop();
}
```

No es muy común y como observaras tambien tendrás un bajo rendimimento.

**¿Cuál es la que tiene mejor Rendimiento?**
De todos los métodos, la forma mas clara de vaciar un arreglo son los métodos 2 y 3 que son muy similares en rendimiento y mas rápida que el método 4. ver este [Benchmark](http://jsben.ch/7QyI1)

> mérito a la comunidad de [stackoverflow en inglés](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1232046/5695795)

Answer (score 6):

Pues, una forma sencilla de eliminarlo sería:

```
A = [];
```

Answer (score 2):

La manera correcta y simple de eliminar el contenido de un array o mejor dicho de vaciar es :

```
array.length=0;
```